# Sonar-runner is unable to generate the issue-report folder

Tags: sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

I am using sonar-runner-2.4 on sonarqube server 4.5.6 ( Windows 7-32 bit).

I am running the analysis on a sample c++ code. 
The strange thing is, the output at console still shows that analysis is complete.

However no issue-report folder gets generated in .sonar folder.

Below is the snippet of console output after running sonar-runner

```
 14:35:58.160 INFO  - Store results in database
 14:35:58.160 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.index.MeasurePersister
 14:35:58.255 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.index.DuplicationPersister
 14:35:58.260 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.index.ComponentDataPersister
 14:35:58.280 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.issue.IssuePersister
 14:35:58.285 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.phases.GraphPersister
 14:35:58.350 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://x.x.x.x:9000/dashboard/index/test_dummy
 14:35:58.350 DEBUG - Evict preview database
 14:35:58.350 DEBUG - Download: http://x.x.x.x:9000/batch_bootstrap/evict?project=1725 (no proxy)
 14:35:58.425 DEBUG - Post-jobs : org.sonar.issuesreport.ReportJob@d718c1 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob@19a2e83 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob@163c13b -> org.sonar.plu
 14:35:58.425 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.issuesreport.ReportJob
 14:35:58.425 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
 14:35:58.425 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
 14:35:58.450 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
 14:35:58.460 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2016-02-05 and 2016-03-03
 14:35:58.460 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2015-03-06 and 2016-02-05
 14:35:58.460 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2011-03-11 and 2015-03-06
 14:35:58.465 INFO  - -> Delete data prior to: 2011-03-11
 14:35:58.470 DEBUG - ==>  Preparing: select * from projects p where p.id=?
 14:35:58.480 DEBUG - ==> Parameters: 1725(Long)
 14:35:58.485 DEBUG - <==      Total: 1
 14:35:58.485 DEBUG - ==>  Preparing: select * from projects where scope='PRJ' and root_id=?
 14:35:58.485 DEBUG - ==> Parameters: 1725(Long)
 14:35:58.490 DEBUG - <==      Total: 0
 14:35:58.490 INFO  - -> Clean test_dummy [id=1725]
 14:35:58.490 INFO  - <- Clean snapshot 16948
 14:35:58.640 DEBUG - Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@1e187ff[id=1725,key=test_dummy,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-test_dummy
 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total time: 5.940s
 Final Memory: 11M/109M
 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Sonar-project.properties file

```
 sonar.projectKey=test_dummy    
 sonar.projectName=test_dummy
 sonar.projectVersion=1.0
 sonar.sources=.

 sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

 sonar.language=c++
```

Is there anything that I am still missing in terms of configuration or anything in general?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Issues Report Plugin [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Issues+Report+Plugin):

> To get an HTML report, set the `sonar.issuesReport.html.enable` property to true

You can also enable this by default in the SonarQube General Settings ('Issues Report' section).

Comment: Thanks @n_stan. Installing the issue report plugin and enabling the HTML report, helped. Actually I installed the issue report plugin but did not enable the HTML report in the General Settings earlier.

Comment: Right, you can also do it in the server settings, answer edited (you should [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it answered your question).